# Django Update Database record is not working

Tags: python, django, sql-update

Iam trying to get a records which works, but it just does not want to update the record...

----forms.py----

```
class acroniform(forms.ModelForm):

    def clean_key(self):
        Key = self.cleaned_data['Key']
        if Acronis.objects.filter(id_iexact=Key).exists():
            raise forms.ValidationError('Dieser Key ist bereits vergeben')
        return Key

    class Meta:
        model = Acronis
        fields = ('KN', 'Key', 'Release')
        labels = {
            'KN': 'Kundennummer',
            'Key': 'Key',
            'Release': 'Release',
        }
```

----urls.py----

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name = 'blog'
urlpatterns = [
path('EditAcronis/<int:id>', views.edit_acronis, name='edit_acronis'),
]
```

----Views.py----

```
@login_required()
    def edit_acronis(request, id=None):
        item = get_object_or_404(Acronis, id=id)
        acroniform_form = acroniform(request.POST or None, instance=item)
        if acroniform_form.is_valid():
            item = acroniform_form.save(commit=False)
            item.save(force_update=True)
            return redirect('/Verwaltung/Acronis')
        else:
            form = acroniform(instance=item)
            return render(request, 'blog/editacronis.html', {'acroniform_form': acroniform_form})
```

----editacronis.html----

```
{% extends 'blog/base.html' %}
{% load bootstrap4 %}

<html lang="en">


<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>{% block supertitle %} Home {% endblock %}</title>
{% block Content %}
<P></P>
    <form class="form-inline, form-row" action="{% url 'blog:acr' %}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% bootstrap_form acroniform_form %}
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Update</button>
    </form>
    <p>Acronis</p>
<P></P>
{% endblock %}
```

What's wrong with my code?

item.save() is not saving or updating the databaserecord...

Comment: Is your editing and updating function is same? Did you check print(item) value return data or not?

Comment: Sry iam a new to django ^^I dont understand how i should check print(item)

Comment: Gorkhali is saying run your test, but inject `print(item)` where item is whatever item whose value you want to check. Then in your console, that item will be printed there. It's a debugging mechanism.

Comment: Also, please add `acroniform` to your question.

Comment: @schillingt i added "acroniform" tried print. It gets the correct value but is still not updating it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
{% extends 'blog/base.html' %}
{% load bootstrap4 %}

<html lang="en">


<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>{% block supertitle %} Home {% endblock %}</title>
{% block Content %}
<P></P>
    <form class="form-inline, form-row" action="" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% bootstrap_form acroniform_form %}
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Update</button>
    </form>
    <p>Acronis</p>
<P></P>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: I also included this:

****
item.save(force_update=True)
        print(item)
        print(acroniform_form)
        return redirect('/Verwaltung/Acronis')
*******

Comment: and the console output was this: 

Acronis object (9)
"GET /Verwaltung/EditAcronis/9 HTTP/1.1" 200 1349
"POST /Verwaltung/Acronis/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
"GET /Verwaltung/Acronis HTTP/1.1" 301 0
"GET /Verwaltung/Acronis/ HTTP/1.1" 200 3160

Comment: @TheFireFox try the above code for the view. Check the console to see of your request reached the acroniform_form.is_valid() method.

Comment: so i included [import pdb; pdb.set_trace()]  over "if acroniform_form.is_valid():"

The question is:   its redirecting me to ""return redirect('/Verwaltung/Acronis')"" but its not doing the save()

Comment: So as i understand --

by clicking on the edit button the code is getting to "if form.is_valid():" then -> jumps to "else" which directs me to "editacronis.html"? 

Does it mean that i need to declare the save() in the html ?? cause its not getting in the True part =?

Comment: @TheFireFox I attempted to replicate your issue with the provided code, however the form does update the object upon submit. If you are reaching the is_valid() method, but are receiving a False response, you would be redirected to the form again. Could you confirm your input is valid as per your models?

Comment: @TheFireFox I just noticed something that may be the cause of your issue! Remove the 'action' url in your form ----editacronis.html---- as per the above edited code. I believe your POST method is being sent to the wrong url by using the action keyword in the form.

Comment: Dear @Andries D. Niemandt,

you just solved my problem, i thank you very much. how could have i not seen that .... 
cheers on you !! :)

Comment: @TheFireFox I'm glad I could help! Happy coding! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
 class acroniform(forms.ModelForm):

    def clean_key(self):
        Key = self.cleaned_data['Key']
        if Acronis.objects.filter(key_iexact=Key).exists():
            raise forms.ValidationError('Dieser Key ist bereits vergeben')
        return Key

    class Meta:
        model = Acronis
        fields = ('KN', 'Key', 'Release')
        labels = {
            'KN': 'Kundennummer',
            'Key': 'Key',
            'Release': 'Release',
        }

@login_required()
    def edit_acronis(request, id):
        item = get_object_or_404(Acronis, id=id)
        form = acroniform(request.POST or None, instance=item)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('/Verwaltung/Acronis')
        else:
            form = acroniform(instance=item)
            return render(request, 'blog/editacronis.html', {'acroniform_form': acroniform_form})
```

or

```
 @login_required()
        def edit_acronis(request, id):
            item = get_object_or_404(Acronis, id=id)
            form = acroniform(request.POST, instance=item)
            if form.is_valid():
                form = acroniform.save(commit=True)
                form.save()
                return redirect('/Verwaltung/Acronis')
            else:
                form = acroniform(instance=item)
                return render(request, 'blog/editacronis.html', {'acroniform_form': acroniform_form})
```

Comment: tried it still no effect in database.
I also checked it with DB Browser for SQLite

Comment: the code is returning "False" at "if form.is_valid():" --> why ?